# What is the Swift alternative of radiansToVector and randomInRange Objective-C functions?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit

I watched an old ios 7 spritekit course and they use these methods. I tried to use them in Swift, but they didn't work. What should I use instead?

```
static inline CGVector radiansToVector(CGFloat radians) {
    CGVector vector;
    vector.dx = cosf(radians);
    vector.dy = sinf(radians);
    return vector;
}

static inline CGFloat randomInRange(CGFloat low, CGFloat high) {
    CGFloat value = arc4random_uniform(UINT32_MAX) / (CGFloat)UINT32_MAX;
    return value * (high - low) + low;
}
```

Comment: Of course it does not work, Objective-C (actually that code is "pure" C) and Swift are two different programming languages. Did you try to *translate* the code? What were your problems, where are you stuck?

Comment: i know i mean i tried to modify the code to suit swift but i didnt modify it well thanks for passing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift re-write:

```
func randomInRange(low: CGFloat, high: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    let value = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UINT32_MAX)) / CGFloat(UINT32_MAX)
    return value * (high - low) + low
}

func radiansToVector(radians: CGFloat) -> CGVector {
    return CGVector(dx: cos(radians), dy: sin(radians))
}
```

UPDATE: More swiftish way of the latter (thanks to @Jessy for pointing out):

```
extension CGVector {
    init(radians: CGFloat) {
        self.dx = cos(radians)
        self.dy = sin(radians)
    }
}
```

Comment: "radiansToVector" isn't really Swift-ish. Ought to be an initializer of CGVector.

Comment: @Jessy since CoreGraphics is C-based framework, `Convenience initializer not allowed in non-class type 'CGVector'`

Comment: hello rshev i have a problem with some code can i mail you directly ?

Comment: @AdeebAbaza please post on StackOverflow so the others could help you also.

Comment: i know but i want to show you the project which i think is not allowed to upload here sorry if i bothering you :(

Comment: also they said i reached my limit of question so i cant post till 2 days

Comment: @rshev Don't use the `convenience` keyword. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31163581/how-to-apply-a-transformation-matrix-to-a-vector-in-scenekit

Comment: @Jessy thanks, added an example.

Comment: The self keyword isn't necessary because dx and dy aren't the names of parameters being passed in.